# :checked selector not working

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, checked

I am trying to get the follow code to work:

**html**

```
<div class = "col-md-4 video text-center wrapper-q1">
     <p class = "no-padding">
        <input class="question1" id = "vraag1" type="radio" name="q1" value="Moon"> <br />
        <label class = "pointer" for = "vraag1">Text</label>
     </p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
input[type="radio"] {
display:none;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height:33px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image: url("../img/radio-btn.png");
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("../img/radio-btn-checked.png");
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

The radio button is shown, but when I click it, it won't change to the "checked" image.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `:before`

CSS:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ label:before {
    content:"";
    background-image: url("../img/radio-btn-checked.png");
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that is not working aswell :( Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `input[type=radio]:checked ~ label`

Instead of

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label
```

will work for you.

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nn14beq/8/)